# MATLAB: Using second output of a function in a inline function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skipping outputs with anonymous function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096281/skipping-outputs-with-anonymous-function-in-matlab)

Say I have a MATLAB function that returns two arguments:

```
[A,B] = twoArgsBack(x)
```

I want to write an anonymous function that uses B (e.g. for passing to a minimization routine)

```
myfun = @(x) sum(twoArgsBack(x))
```

will return the sum of A, ignoring the output from B.  How can I write an anonymous function that returns the sum of B?

Comment: Duplicate\Related: [Skipping outputs with anonymous function in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096281/skipping-outputs-with-anonymous-function-in-matlab), [define anonymous function as 2 of 4 outputs of m file function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673392/define-anonymous-function-as-2-of-4-outputs-of-m-file-function)

Comment: I agree, voted to close.