# Anonymous function with a variable-length argument list

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

Can I create an anonymous function that accepts a variable number of arguments?

I have a struct array `S` with a certain field, say, `bar`, and I want to pass all the `bar` values to my anonymous function `foo`. Since the number of elements in struct `S` is unknown, `foo` must be able to accept a variable number of arguments.

The closest thing that I've been able to come up with is passing a cell array as the input argument list:

```
foo({arg1, arg2, arg3, ...})
```

and I'm invoking it with `foo({S.bar})`, but it looks very awkward.

Creating a special m-file just for that seems like an overkill. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `varargin` as the argument of the anonymous function, you can pass a variable number of inputs.

For example:

```
foo = @(varargin)fprintf('you provided %i arguments\n',length(varargin))
```

Usage

```
s(1:4) = struct('bar',1);
foo(s.bar)

you provided 4 arguments
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `varagin` can be used in anonymous function, and the answer was right under my nose :) For that matter, you could've used `nargin` instead of `length(varargin)` :)

Comment: @EitanT: I realize I could have used `nargin`, but I wanted some simple manipulation that would employ `varargin`

Answer (score 0):

- va_arg in matlab called [varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) here is the content of the link
  :

> varargin is an input variable in a function definition statement that
>   allows the function to accept any number of input arguments.

```
function varlist(varargin)
   fprintf('Number of arguments: %d\n',nargin);
   celldisp(varargin)

varlist(ones(3),'some text',pi)


Number of arguments: 3

varargin{1} =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

varargin{2} =
some text

varargin{3} =
    3.1416
```

- [define anonymous function as 2 of 4 outputs of m file function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673392/define-anonymous-function-as-2-of-4-outputs-of-m-file-function)