# Pass empty function handle as argument MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a code likt this:

```
bla = {[], @fftshift, @ifftshift};

for aa=1:numel(bla)

for bb=1:numel(bla)

   for cc=1:numel(bla)

      for dd=1:numel(bla)

          [~, ~, ~] = somefunction(bla{aa}, bla{bb}, bla{cc}, bla{dd});
      end

   end

end

end
```

And in `somefunction` I have

```
Y = func1(fft(func2(blablabla)));
```

where func1 and func2 are substituted by bla{aa} and bla{bb}.

If I run this code I get an error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

How can I tell Matlab that I don't want to pass any function as argument, so that e.g. for first iteration I would have

```
(fft((blablabla)))
```

**EDIT**

I already tried writing an "empty" function and passing its handle as argument

```
function donothing()
end

bla = {@donothing, @fftshift, @ifftshift};
```

and simply

```
bla = {[], @fftshift, @ifftshift};
```

or

```
bla = {'', @fftshift, @ifftshift};
```

But in all cases I got `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` or `Too many input arguments.`

Comment: Pass a handle to an identity function instead of an empty array: `h = @(x) x`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I get `Too many input arguments.`

Comment: Aha, so you want a function with multiple inputs and outputs. If you have a specific number of arguments you can do `h = @(x1, x2, x3) deal(x1, x2, x3)`, for example for 3 arguments.

Comment: And it turns out [you can use `varargin` in anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614600/anonymous-function-with-a-variable-length-argument-list) as well, so you would do `h = @(varargin) deal(varargin)`.

Comment: No, that also produces `Too many input arguments.`

Comment: If I write `@(varargin) varargin` it gives me `Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`

Comment: You forgot the 'deal'

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: I'll have to check when I have a MATLAB machine, then.

Comment: Does a function `function varargout = doNothing(varargin)` with the contents `varargout = varargin;` work?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. Could you please post is as answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on hbaderts's comment the answer is

```
function varargout = doNothing(varargin)
    varargout = varargin;
end
```